# is 'continue' what I'm looking for?

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, continue

Given this code:

```
while($thisrow = mysqli_fetch_array($thisresult)){
    if($thisrow['displaythis'] == 'yes'){
        echo $thisrow['name'];
    } else {
        continue;
    }
        $associatedquery = "select * from database where id = $thisrow['associated']";
        $result = mysqli_query($associatedquery);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['name'];
        }
 }
```

If $thisrow['displaythis'] == no, is it going to 'continue' to process the associatedquery, or is it going to go back to the next value in the first while statement? If not, how can I jump back to the next value in the first while statement and skip the associatedquery? I know I can put the whole 'associatedquery' segment inside the if = 'yes' statement, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Continue goes to the next iteration of the loop. http://es1.php.net/continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue skips further processing of current iteration and goes to the next iteration.

Comment: +1, but this would be a better answer if it (1) linked to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) and (2) explicitly answered the question ("Yes, `continue` is what you want").

Comment: Nice `copy/paste` answer :-)

Comment: is an 'iteration' strictly a 'while' or 'for each' loop, or is an 'if' also an iteration?

Comment: if is not an iteration. its a conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, continue will go back to the loop statement and start over with the next value in the loop, it will not execute any of the lower half of your loop after the continue statement.  If statements are not loops, but `for`, `while`, and `switch` statements are considered loops in php

So the answer to your question is **YES**

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) is a more in depth explanation

Answer (score 0):

Q: **Is it going to go back to the next value in the first while statement?**

A: **Yes**, because `continue` will 'continue' checking for the expected value from the `if` condition in the loop and skip the execution of the rest of the code until you `break` the loop or it finishes.

**Check some examples and usage at:**

https://www.php.net/continue